# How to find if collision between two scene nodes ended in ARKit-Scenekie of ios 11?

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios11, arkit, xcode9beta6

I implemented physics contact delegate in order to find out the contact between two nodes. Upon contact, the delegate is getting called correctly and i am changing the color of the nodes. But contact didEnd method is called again and again and hence i couldn't find out when the actual contact ended.

For example, if i move one object to overlap with the other, i am changing the color of the objects. But when i again move the second object outwards and if there is no contact, again i have to change back the color to original one. How to achieve this?

There is method to tell that there is some contact but there is no method to tell that the contact is no more.